# Characterisation of pretopological convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, filters

I'm reading

> Convergence foundations of topology - Dolecki and Mynard

and I am somewhat surprised by their proposition V.1.1 which states that

> A convergence $\xi$ on a set $X$ is a pretopology if and only if
> $$ x\in \lim_\xi F \implies \mathcal{V}_\xi(x) \leq F, $$
> where $\mathcal{V}_\xi(x)$ is the vicinity filter at $x\in X$.

Surely the implication should be reversed? I would have thought that this implication is true for any convergence, not just pretopological ones. Unfortunately they do not give a proof. I checked the errata at https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/9012/suppl_file/9012_errata.pdf, but it is not mentioned.

---

Some of the relevant definitions:

> Let $X$ be a set. A convergence on $X$ is a relation between filters on $X$ and elements of $X$ (we write $x\in \lim_\xi F$ if $\xi$ relates the filter $F$ to $x$, in other words $\lim_\xi$ is the image function of the relation) such that
>
> - $\lim_\xi$ is order-preserving: $F \leq G \implies \lim_\xi F \subseteq \lim_\xi G;$
> - $\lim_\xi$ is centered: for all $x\in X: x \in \lim_\xi \uparrow\{x\}$, where $\uparrow\{x\}$ is the principal filter generated by $\{x\}$.

> The vicinity filter of a convergence $\xi$ at $x$ is defined as
> $$ \mathcal{V}_\xi(x) := \bigwedge_{x\in \lim_\xi F} F $$

> A convergence is a pretopology if at each point $x$ there exists a filter $G$ that converges to $x$ such that
> $$ F \in {\lim_\xi}^{-1}(x) \implies G \leq F. $$

Many thanks for any pointers!

Comment: The order on the set of filters is just inclusion? So $F \le G$ is just $F \subseteq G$ and the lattice operations are wrt this order? Just to be sure (it would seem to be logical)

Comment: [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopological+space) might be relevant too.

Comment: Yes exactly, it is just set inclusion. Thanks for the link!

Comment: So nLab effectively defines a pretopology as a convergence $\xi$ such that $x\in \lim_\xi\mathcal{V}_\xi(x)$. Which, it would seem to me, is clearly equivalent to the definition of Dolecki / Mynard. The proposition is still strange, however.

Comment: In the last definition they suggest that that $G$ is the vicinity filter of $x$ but they don't say so. nLab demands it.

Comment: Surely if there is such a filter $G$, then it is the vicinity filter? Because the vicinity filter is the infimum of $\lim^{-1}(x)$ and $G$ is the least element.

Comment: A little later in the book (proof of Proposition V.2.12) they apply the property in Proposition V.1.1 to a convergence that is not necessarily pretopological. I think my conclusion is therefore correct and the implication should be reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \in \lim\limits_\xi F$ always implies $\mathcal{V}_\xi(x) \le F$, because by definition $\mathcal{V}_\xi(x)$ is the lower bound of all such $F$. So the forward implication in $$x\in \lim_\xi F \implies \mathcal{V}_\xi(x) \leq F$$ is a definition consequence.

If however $$\mathcal{V}_\xi(x) \leq F \implies x\in \lim_\xi F$$ we can conclude in particular that $\mathcal{V}_\xi(x)$ converges to $x$, which is what the definition of pretopology (in terms of convergence) in the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopological+space#convergence_structure) tells us to check. It also implies that we can take $G=\mathcal{V}_\xi(x)$ in your book's definition.

So with the implication the other way, we get agreement with another source and an easy proof (so rightly omitted) within the text's framework.
So in short, I agree with the assessment of the OP.